# Bind data to asp.net controls like wpf datacontext binding

Tags: asp.net

Hi I was wondering if there is any way to bind my server side panel which contains multiple textboxes ,so my textboxes show associated bound fields which coming from data base automatically .
something like this:
in code behind:

```
myPnl.DataSource=myContext.TableName;
```

in aspx page:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="myPnl">

<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' ID="txtTitle" ReadOnly="true">
```

Comment: Use some Itemlist controls (like asp:repeater or asp:gridview). And add ItemTemplate (in that add textbox with text="<%# EVal('Title')%>"). But, if you want save the change you need to work bit more..